# How to remove the stop words in a meaningful way using Lucene

Tags: lucene, stop-words, text-analysis

I'm using `org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer` to remove the stop words and also stem a phrase. However what happens is when I have a phrase like "heart and heart disease", that the analyzer does is it removes the "and" from the middle of the phrase which turns it into a meaningless phrase (the output is "heart heart disease"). How can I cope this problem and remove stop words only if it is necessary?

Comment: Only if it's necessary?  What does that mean?  And what output are you referring to?  Stop words are removed because they aren't meaningful search terms, and analysis is only generally designed to affect the indexed form of the text.  It shouldn't affect the stored text returned in search results.

Comment: if you look at the example I have in my post you'll get some idea what I mean by 'if it is necessary'.

Comment: I read it, and no, still no idea.  "and" is a stop word, and I see nothing unusual *in the least* about it being removed from that phrase.  Why wouldn't it be removed?

Comment: 'heart and heart disease' is a single phrase and removing 'and' from it makes it a meaningless phrase!!

Comment: But that's the analyzed form.  Again, it shouldn't effect the version you stored (which is returned from `IndexSearcher.doc(int)`, for instance).  The analysis isn't supposed to result in a complete english sentence.  It's to provide a sequence of terms which are useful for search.  Take:  "this is an example sentence for your perusal".  After stemming and stop word removal, it becomes, I believe:  "exampl sentenc your perus"

Comment: @H.Z. There is no way to tell this to lucene this is all together some quote spoken by Lincoln so do not rip off stop words. You can write your own analyser and do it there. This is machine learning task.

Comment: Why would you expect *any* text after stop word removal and stemming to be meaningful? These processes *will* turn it into a form suitable for indexing and searching, and nothing else. Just use the same analyzer for your search query, it'll match the phrase just fine.

Comment: The reason I'd like the text to be meaningful after the stemming and stop word removal is that I'm not using the text for search. I'm actually using it for a keyword extraction task so the polished text should be meaningful because it is considered as a keyword. I think I should write my own Analyzer to only remove the leading stop words.